# Filter function in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a function that, for a given row, returns all other rows where column B is equal to the value in given row column B AND Column J is "Yes".

In google sheets, this is what I am using but it gives me an error in Excel. Is there an equivalent in excel?

```
=filter(B:B,B:B=B2,J:J="Yes")>1
```

Comment: In Excel, you can use the `Advanced Filter`

Comment: Can I use advance filter in a formula within a cell?

Comment: No you cannot. Examine Excel HELP for Advanced filter to learn how to use it.

Comment: Sort of related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010265/how-to-add-multiple-conditions-when-using-array-formula-with-index-and-match/50010538#50010538